# how to update swap values of two rows with single query

Tags: mysql, swap

Is there a query with which i can exchange the values of two rows with single query?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can see the solution in this article

http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/

look at the : **The elegant way** , make a join to get the data from the 2 rows to be swapped in 1 row, after that make an update is easy.

example :

```
UPDATE
rules AS rule1
JOIN rules AS rule2 ON
( rule1.rule_id = 1 AND rule2.rule_id = 4 )
SET
rule1.priority = rule2.priority,
rule2.priority = rule1.priority
;
```

Comment: What if you want to swap the last 2 rows ?

Answer (score 9):

```
UPDATE my_table SET a=@tmp:=a, a=b, b=@tmp;
```

Comment: Your solution is for swapping two columns, the question was about swapping two rows.

Comment: I was searching how to swap two columns, great solution :)

Comment: it's useful , and simple.