# How to swap-update values in a field

Tags: mysql

These [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517219/how-to-update-swap-values-of-two-rows-with-single-query) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203202/sql-update-order-of-evaluation) are related to this question I guess, but I do not find a way out to solve my requirement which is slightly different.

I have a table, say like this:

```
fruit         color
--------------------
mango          red
apple          red
orange         yellow
banana         green
```

I need to `UPDATE` field `color` in such a way that `red` becomes `yellow` and `yellow` becomes `red`. Here is how the table should look like after update query.

```
fruit         color
--------------------
mango          yellow
apple          yellow
orange         red
banana         green
```

This query wont work obviously.

```
UPDATE plant SET color = 'yellow' WHERE color = 'red';
UPDATE plant SET color = 'red' WHERE color = 'yellow'
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're updating `fruit` in your example query, not `color`

Comment: @lanzz oh silly error, let me correct it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single query:

```
UPDATE plant 
SET    color = IF(color = 'yellow', 'red', IF(color = 'red', 'yellow', color))
WHERE  color IN ('red', 'yellow');
```

Comment: Just what I was about to say! :)  Although I'd be tempted to use a single `CASE` expression rather than the nested `IF` - but is only for readability, really.

Comment: I tend to avoid `CASE` when the choices are few, the additional noise keywords make for a less-readable query in my eyes.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE plant SET color = CASE color
    WHEN 'yellow' THEN 'red'
    WHEN 'red'    THEN 'yellow'
  END
WHERE color IN ('red', 'yellow')
```

Comment: Thank eggyal, I like this answer better.