# MySQL swap column values of two rows without violating the unique contraint?

Tags: mysql, unique, swap

Similar to [How to swap values of two rows in MySQL without violating unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint), but not quite..

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `html_text` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `html_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

It represents links in a navigation area of a website. E.g.: a link to the homepage, a link to the contact page, etc. I want to be able to change the order of these links, that's why I have the column `order`. The values of this column are unique, so I can sort by `order`.

Now I want to swap the positions of two links in this ordered list, so I want to swap the values of `order`. But unlike the other question, I do not know the value's of the `order`-fields, I only know the `id` values of the two rows I want to swap. I'd like to have only one query.

Can anybody help me with this, as I'm not very experienced with complex MySQL queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straight forward logic for this in a single query.

Conside you want to swap `x,y`

1. You have to update first `x` with a different value `z`. (Some logic to arrive at a very unique value is required here).
2. Then update `y` as `x`
3. Then update `z` as `y`

Comment: So 3 update queries is the only way to go, assuming I know z in advance? (for instance, I know -1 is never used in my table)

Comment: Yes. That's the best way! I know.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll approve this since it's most likely the best answer I'll get on this.

Comment: Minimum of 2 updates are needed but Rajaganesh is correct. You can't do this with 1 update in MySQL, unfortunately.

Comment: You are totally wrong! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517219/how-to-update-swap-values-of-two-rows-with-single-query

Comment: @JacekKowalewski That answer doesn't work with a Unique Index on the columns.