# Update multiple row with multiple where Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

is it possible to update multiple row with multiple where?

```
    id | formid
   PK 1  | 2
   PK 2  | 2
```

i need to switch id 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 also need to filter with where formid = 2. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that...by using this query

```
update mytbl a
inner join mytbl b on a.formid <> b.formid
set a.id = b.id
where a.id in (1,2) and b.id in (1,2)
```

Comment: how about switching between id ?

Comment: id | formid
1 | 20
2 | 20

i want to switch the id of them .

Comment: that is what i have given to you as a answer...!!which may help you probably @IbnuHabibie

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything that does not work?

This is a problem of switching 2 values. You can try with temporary variable as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql).

Another option in by join, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517219/how-to-update-swap-values-of-two-rows-with-single-query).